# Change ImageView Background in listView onItemSelected Android

Tags: android, android-listview

My listview contains 2 TextViews and an ImageView.  I used an adapter to fill ListView. When i click on a row item i want the background image of positioned at item clicked to change. I am using setOnItemClickListener() shown below

```
lvRMultiple.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

             mp3Url = trackList.get(position).getPreview().toString();
             title = trackList.get(position).getTitle().toString();
             playStreamMusic();



            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Clicked :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and my getView() method is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ecran_multiple_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txIndex = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txIndex);
            holder.txSTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txSTitle);
            holder.btOnOFF = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.btOnOFF);
            vi.setTag(holder);


        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


        return vi;
    }



}
```

How can I change imageView background on item selection ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a Selector. It's an xml file that references multiple drawable or color and tell when Android should use it.

It's something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_enabled="false"><color android:color="#50b1b1b1" />
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/borderless_background_shape" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/borderless_background_shape" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true"><color android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</item>

</selector>
```

Take a look at this for more information : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 vRMultiple.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

         mp3Url = trackList.get(position).getPreview().toString();
         title = trackList.get(position).getTitle().toString();
         playStreamMusic();

         //find your ImageView using the view provided by the event
         ImageView imgview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btOnOFF);
         //And change its background here
         imgview.setBackgroundDrawable(....);


         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Clicked :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: it works but when i scroll down the imgview return to default and also  when clicked on a second row both imageview change it should be single choice